# explicit ctor of unscoped-enum and it's underlying type

Tags: c++, enums

Is it safe to declare a class that accepts both unscoped enum and its underlying type as an explicit constructor?

```
enum category : int {
  a, b
}

struct foo {
  explicit foo(category c) {} // #1
  explicit foo(int x) {}      // #2
};

foo f1(3);   // #2 is called
foo f2(a);   // #1 is called
foo f3((a)); // #1 is called
```

I know that using scoped enum is preferred, but I just wonder that does the standard guarantees that the above is well-overloaded?

Comment: No time to find a standard reference so I wont post as an answer but yes, this should be well defined.

Comment: What do you mean by "safe"?

Comment: @Jarod42 What I meant was that does enum type always invokes `#1` and int type always invokes `#2`. Updated comment in the code.

Comment: A bit of a strange case, but given `struct S { operator short() const; operator category() const; }; foo f4(S{});`, clang++ and g++ say ambiguous overload, and MSVC with `/permissive-` compiles using `S::operator category() const` and `foo::foo(category)`. Not sure yet which is correct.

Comment: Wait, I'm not sure about MSVC now. It's currently acting weird on godbolt.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, an exact match is better than an integral conversion from the enumeration type, per [over.ics.scs].  There being no implicit conversion **to** an enumeration type, any other integer (or unscoped enumeration) type will select the `int` overload (unlike the case of `short` and `long` being ambiguous with an `int` argument).